# How do you clean cheesecloth full of bean roots?

Tags: cleaning, sprouting

Related: [How do you clean cheesecloth?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81485/how-do-you-clean-cheesecloth)

My problem is a bit more complex. I sprout beans in cheesecloth and it's been working okay. The cheesecloth is able to get some of the bean roots off the beans when I harvest the bean sprouts so that I don't have to eat a lot of roots. The drawback: I end up with a piece of cheesecloth full of bean roots. Handwashing it helps remove some but not all the roots. Better ideas?

Comment: The best use for cheesecloth when sprouting is to cover a glass jar; the beans only touch the fabric when tipping the jar for draining the water then the jar goes cloth side up again.

Comment: @Luciano it sounds like the roots getting stuck in the cloth is considered a feature in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You clean it by throwing it away. Is it worth the trouble?

Comment: Lol. Good point!